# main files and module import errors

Tags: python

[image: file structure]

Hi, I've been stuck on this problem a while, and all other questions around this issue on this site haven't helped fix the issue.
In the `main.py` file, I'm trying to import the `datastorer` function which sits in the `StoreData.py` file.
I've created empty `_init_.py` files in the project root, DataStore
folder and also Calculations folder.
I'm importing using :

```
from project.DataStore.StoreData import datastorer
```

But always get the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.DataStore'.

I've tried adding

```
myDir = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(myDir)
```

to the top of the file which wasn't successful.
I'm wondering if it's something to do with the name of the file `main`. Although I need to keep this as the file name. If anyone has any ideas this would be great thank you!

Comment: I mean it's weird that you place your main file deep into the hierarchy of the project and not on the top level but that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Does `import project` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your current folder to python path, then all you imports should not refer to `project` so try

```
from DataStore.StoreData import datastorer
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Ive tried your suggest but i still receive the error. How can i ensure that the current folder is added to python path? thanks

Comment: either you start python from the project root, either you add the project folder to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of `main.py` you can add

```py
import sys
from os.path import dirname
sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(dirname(__file__))))
```